# Aggregation on a nested field in elasticsearch using latest Java SDK

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have an index mapping like so:

```
...
     "domain": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "store": true
          },
          "tld": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "store": true
          },
          "sld": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "store": true
          },
          "subdomains": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "store": true
          }
        }
      },
...
```

I'd like to get a terms aggregation of the `sld` field, but when I try it using the `co.elastic.clients:elasticsearch-java` library the nested aggregation API seems incomplete.

For example:

```
elasticsearch.search(s -> s.index(INDEX)
                            .size(0)
                            .aggregations("nesting", 
                               n -> n.nested(
                                  nesting -> nesting.path("domain"). 
                                  NO OPTIONS TO ADD A TERMS AGG HERE
                               )
                            )
                    , Void.class);
```

I'm currently using `co.elastic.clients:elasticsearch-java:7.16.2` but have also tried with the latest `7.x` client library.

Is it just not possible? If so, how?

### Update

I've tried using this:

```
            Aggregation subAggregation = new Aggregation.Builder()
                    .terms(new TermsAggregation.Builder().field("domain.sld").size(100).build())
                    .build();

            Aggregation nestedAggregation = new Aggregation.Builder()
                    .nested(new NestedAggregation.Builder().path("domain").build())
                    .aggregations("slds", subAggregation)
                    .build();

elasticsearch.search(s -> s.index(INDEX)
                            .size(0)
                            .aggregations("nesting", nestedAggregation)
                    , Void.class);
```

When I run the query generated directly against elasticsearch I get the right result back, but using the java SDK I can't access the buckets:

```
NestedAggregate nestedAggregate = results.aggregations().get("nesting").nested() ... // what now? No options
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with version 7.16.2 of the client library.

Once upgraded to 7.17.18 then `NestedAggregate` finally gets an `aggregations` method whereby you can then access the sub aggregation, in this use case like so:

```
StringTermsAggregate termsAggregate = results.aggregations()
  .get("nested")
  .nested()
  .aggregations()
  .get("slds")
  .sterms();
```